# Angular's ng-class: combine enumerated (array) classes and condition-based ones?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have an array with classes set in the controller (has to be this way, it's read from page's meta-template).  I'd also like to have a conditional classes applied to the same element.  Is it possible?

Edit, more info: my html element has classes that originate from two sources - one is a set of classes created by the controller (they are provided by a service outside of my code, I can't have them hardcoded in the view).  The other source is an output of a condition (for example: if "$scope.activeElement === name_of_this_element, add 'active' class).
In ng-class directive, I can't use an object notation for unspecified list of classes (the first source) and I have to use an object notation for conditional classes.

Edit: found a solution (see below).

Comment: you really should provide a lot more detail if you want reasonable answers

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah, I know.  The kid started crying and I knew I wasn't going to be able to sit down for the rest of the evening, I could either not ask the question or do it at once :-).

Anyways, I added some more detail and a possible solution.  Please feel free to share your insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution - I placed the "fixed" classes in a regular class attribute (converted that string to an array first) and conditional ones in ng-class object, like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" class="{{cell.cssClass}}" ng-class="{active: condition}">
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to write an ng-class in this way

```
<div ng-class="[item.class, item.errorClass, item.locked ? 'locked-item' : '']"></div>
```

Comment: When needing multiple classes added dynamically using conditionals and wanting at least one of the classes to be set by a function, this is the only variation I could find that would work.

Comment: This also was the only option that worked for me. I needed to mix a fixed class and one coming from a function:  ng-class="['fixedClass', styleManager.getItemClass($index)]"

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you stored a array of classes' name is not relevant here.

HTML

```
<div ng-class="arrOfClasses[condition]"></div>
```

Angular

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arrOfClasses = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];

    $scope.condition = 1; // what ever number here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way, and also to avoid using {{}} inside class would be with just an expression:

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" ng-class="(condition ? 'active ' : '') + cell.cssClass">
```